# How to transfer data from a view to a method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

There is a Customer controller, it has the DeleteCustomer action method.

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel> customers =
    _customerRepository.GetAllCustomers().Select(s => new
    CustomerViewModel
    {
        CustomerId = s.CustomerId,
        Name = s.Name,
        Adress = s.Adress
    });

    return View("Index", customers);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DeleteCustomer(int id)
{
    _customerRepository.Delete(id);
    return LocalRedirect("~/Customer/Index");
}
}
```

Here is the link, when clicked, the action method should work, the Id of the user I want to delete should fly into the method. But he writes an error 405. Somewhere I was mistaken I can not understand exactly where. I would be grateful for your help. I think the tag "a" is a Get request. Use @Html.ActionLink()?

```
 <a asp-action="DeleteCustomer" asp-route-id="@item.CustomerId">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Create a form and put the tag "a" in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `DeleteCustomer` only responds to POST, but HTML links are always requested via GET. However, `DeleteCustomer` *should* require a POST, so don't change that. Instead, you need to use a form like:

```
<form asp-action="DeleteCustomer" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@item.CustomerId" />
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Then, if you want the button to *look* like a link, you can simply style it to look that way. If you're using Bootstrap, you can just apply the `btn-link` class to it.